# jQuery: Dynamically add file upload fields in form and validate total size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

Is it possible to use jQuery to calculate/validate/restrict total upload size of dynamically added file fields? The form will be sending the content as an email copy, so it should be limiting the total upload size to eg. 20MB or so. The backend validation is no problem (by PHP).

The validation could either be done 'on the fly' or when hitting submit.

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <a href="#" class="add_field_button">+ Add</a>
  <div>
    <input type="file" name="attachment[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="file" name="attachment[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yyqnwfb9/1/

Any input on how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Update: New Fiddle with implemented solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yyqnwfb9/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to get the size. For example, to get total size in bytes of all files in the page:

```js
function getTotal() {
  var total = 0;

  $(':file').each(function() {    
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      total += this.files[0].size;
    }
  });

  return total;
}

$(function() {
  var maxSize = 3 * 1000 * 1000 ; // ~3MB
  $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {    
    if (getTotal() > maxSize) {
      // Clear field
      $(this).val('');
      // Display error?
      $('#total').append(' Too big');
    } else {
      // Update total
      $('#total').text(getTotal());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">
<input type="file" name="attachment[]">

<strong>Total Bytes: <span id="total">0</span></strong>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Pablo, it looks promising. I have tried to implement the function but I do not get it working. It you have the time I would be really grateful for a Fiddle implementation.

Comment: @TNF Added a working snippet using the original `getTotal()` function.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Pablo, I really appreciate it! It works flawlessly. In case anyone's interested, I've updated the question with a working Fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

i have set file size limit of **3MB** in upload function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

  var x = 1;
  var uploadField = document.getElementById("file");

  uploadField.onchange = function() {
      if(this.files[0].size > 307200){
         alert("File is too big!");
         this.value = "";
      }
      else{
              $(add_button).click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          if (x < max_fields) {
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="file" name="attachment[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
          }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent('div').remove();
          x--;
        })
            }

        };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <a href="#" class="add_field_button">+ Add</a>
  <div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="attachment[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The add button in the op's code adds another input field, this one doesn't have an ID, so one can upload more than 3mb

Comment: Thanks for your response Nihal. This is great for validating/limiting each file for maximum size, but I was looking for a way to sum up the size of all files added in total.